# Calculate business days difference between two days excluding holidays?

Tags: java

I already have a list of holidays which is a List .

Given two Date object, how could I calculate the difference in working days **(not counting weekends and holidays)** between them?

I have found the library ObjectLab Kit but I think it only knows how to advance days.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found [Jollyday](http://jollyday.sourceforge.net/) useful in earlier projects.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most efficient way, but probably fast enough: loop starting with the earliest date, add a day at each iteration until the end date, and increment a counter unless the current day is a weekend or a holiday.

`java.util.Calendar` is the class to use. It has method to add a day to itself and check if it's a saturday or a sunday.